# Synonym trigger and triggers

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigger) - 29 questions
[triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggers) - 202 questions

The singular tag name seems redundant. I'd suggest that [triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggers) be kept, and the other be synonym'd.

Comment: Agree, `triggers` sounds more appropriate to me too. What's also very appropriate is that it's got its info completed while the other one hasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Grant, this makes perfect sense. I've created the synonym and merged the tags.

There are a few more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) that should probably also happen, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Merging the two is obviously a good idea.

I only ever pick a plural word for tags if the matter itself deals with multiple instances on principal. Here, it should be just [trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigger). The appended `s` for the plural is noise, carrying no additional information. Just my opinion ...

Comment: sounds right to me, the same as table names. If you spot any that are wrong feel free to let us know

Comment: @JackDouglas: Exactly, I was thinking of table names, too.